# How to create a symbolic link when target directory doesn't exist?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Is there a flag you can add to the `ln` command to force the creation of the target directory structure (like `mkdir -p`).

Consider :

```
ln -s /Applications/'Sublime Text.app'/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/
```

Which adds a symlink to the Sublime Text command line tool. But it fails if /usr/local/bin/ doesn't exist.

I've tried the `-f` 'force' flag but that doesn't help.

Do you need to test wether /usr/local/bin/ exists and create it if it doesn't before running the `ln` command or is there a fancier way to do it?

Comment: does the file path go in place of "${!#}" and "$@" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this,

```
mkdir -p  /create_your_path/ && xargs ln -s /link_file_path/file /create_your_path/
```

Comment: Yeah, I came to this conclusion eventually. mkdir -p has no effect if the directory already exists and creates it if it doesn't so it works well.

Comment: What's with the `xargs` pipeline? `mkdir` produces no output so the pipeline to `xargs` is just a really obscure way of saying `mkdir -p target; ln -s source target`; and you lose the exit code from `mkdir`, so you can't fail if the target isn't a directory or you lack permissions to create it.

Comment: Yeah the `xargs` doesn't seem to make sense here.

Comment: downvoted for xargs  which makes absolutely zero sense here

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no standard option to `ln` to create a missing target directory.  Use `install` or `mkdir -p` before `ln`, perhaps in a helper script if you find you need this more than once.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
mkdir -p "${!#}"
exec ln -s "$@"
```

This is obviously not very robust, but feel free to embellish it with more sanity checks if you think you really find it useful.

Comment: `${!#}` is a Bash feature so this is `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bin/sh`.